# How do I reference a field name which includes a slash in Power Query

Tags: powerquery

In Excel 2016 Get & Transform ("Power Query") it appears to be totally valid to have a field (column) name containing a slash character. However, when I try to reference this column, I can't find any way to escape the slash to make the reference work. How can I do this?

Specifically, the following code is accepted:

```
Table.AddColumn(#"Capitalize", "ABC Table", each Table.FromColumns({Text.Split([ABC], ",")}))
```

...but the following is not:

```
Table.AddColumn(#"Capitalize", "ABC Table", each Table.FromColumns({Text.Split([ABC / DEF], ",")}))
```

...presumably because of the slash in `[ABC / DEF]`.

How can I escape this slash?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try using `[#"ABC / DEF"]` instead of `[ABC / DEF]`.

Comment: Thanks, one of the few combinations I hadn't tried...!

Comment: For anyone else that might been confused, the `[ ]` part is record notation, irrelevant from the field name issue with the special character. So any field name with special characters can be referred to with `#"field with special / character"`.